# Подключение библиотек scilab в java

Tags: java, scilab

Делаю все через intellij idea. Подключил библиотеки:

```
org.scilab.modules.javasci.jar;
org.scilab.modules.types.jar;
org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar
```

(<kbd>file</kbd> -> <kbd>project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>modules</kbd> -> <kbd>dependencies</kbd>, плюсик и добавил через scilab)

Сам код взял из примера:

```
import org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab;
import org.scilab.modules.types.ScilabType;
import org.scilab.modules.types.ScilabDouble;

class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
            Scilab sci = new Scilab();
            sci.open();
            sci.exec("disp(%pi);");

            ScilabDouble a = new ScilabDouble(3.14);
            sci.put("a",a);
            sci.exec("b=sin(a);");
            ScilabType b = sci.get("b");
            System.out.println("b = " + b);

            sci.close();

      } catch (org.scilab.modules.javasci.JavasciException e) {
            System.err.println("An exception occurred: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

    }
}
```

и в итоге выдает:

> ```
> The native library javasci does not exist or cannot be found.
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no javasci in java.library.path
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
>   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_ScilabJNI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_Scilab.SetFromJavaToON(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.initScilab(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at Matrixs.main(Matrixs.java:19)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_ScilabJNI.SetFromJavaToON()V
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_ScilabJNI.SetFromJavaToON(Native Method)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_Scilab.SetFromJavaToON(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.initScilab(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at Matrixs.main(Matrixs.java:19)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
> ```

Что то не правильно подключил? Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить или же как сделать по правильному.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа при запуске не может найти `libjavasci.dll`. Попробуйте добавить путь к этой библиотеке в переменную окружения PATH. Она должна быть где-то тут: `C:\Program Files\scilab-XXXX\bin`

Либо можно попробовать положить эту dll в папку с проектом.

Comment: а если такой dll нет??

Comment: а у вас сам scilab установлен?

Comment: да scilab-5.5.2 (64-bit)

Comment: я смотрел там где вы сказали и такого нет(

Comment: И в Program Files (x86) тоже нет? А сама папка со scilab есть? Попробуйте сделать поиск по имени dll на диске C

Comment: сам scilab находится в Program Files,прогнал поиск по всему диску С libjavasci.dll. не найден.Может у меня не тот scilab??ну версия какая нибудь другая должна быть?